# Most efficient way to sort a collection of arrays based off the order of a seperate array

Tags: javascript

Yes I am aware of similar questions but it doesn't quite cover my use case here.

I'm having trouble finding a way to bring the time complexity of this down

I have two objects like so

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    id: 1,
    fruitInBasket: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    id: 2,
    fruitInBasket: 4
  }
]
```

```js
const homes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    familyMembers: [
      {
        name: 'James',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Steve',
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    familyMembers: [
      {
        name: 'James',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Steve',
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so one is a collection of `people` with a count of fruit in a basket and the other is a collection of `homes` and within each home is the same users as in the `people` collection.

Now I want to order the users in each home based on the count of `fruitInBasket` so I have done this

```js
// create an empty table to store the order of the people
let orderTable = {};

// order the people based off the count in fruitInBasket using lodash orderBy
people = orderBy(people, ['fruitInBasket'], ['desc']);

// create the table 
orderTable = people.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [item.id]: index
  }
}, {});

// order the people in each home based on the order in the `orderTable`
homes.forEach((home) => {
  let members = [];
  home.familyMembers.forEach((member) => {
    let i = orderTable[member.id];
    members[i] = member;
  });
  home.familyMembers = members;
})
```

so immediately you can see a nested for loop - which is never ideal.. but I can't figure out a way around this. This method has to sort through quite a lot of data and I am noticing huge performance issues.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is your `people` structure changeable?

Comment: if your data set per people/home set is small enough, but you have a very large amount of people/home sets, prebuilding the ordering map could be slower due to object initialization overhead, and djcaesar9114's solution would end up being faster.  At that point, optimizing for this: https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds and making sure that the arrays you iterate are homogeous and  have no "holes" will be orders of magnitude faster due to native array access.  Getting rid of function calls and object initialization and other micro-optimizations will then be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be O(N log N).  Its performance bottleneck is the one time sort.  Everything else is just O(N) iteration.  Some microoptimizations still possible.
Generate an ordered map lookup table.
Just move arrays based on that mapping.

There is a hpc sort library that is measured around 10-40x faster than built-in JavaScript on benchmarks that can be added to increase performance.

I'm not sure, but is the familyMember table the same for every home object?  Can you not just copy the same familyMember array to every object or do they have different properties?
Extra optimization per home could be to convert above table to index to index mapping, so that native level array indexing will be used for subsequent ordering.

```js
const orderMap = Object.fromEntries(people.sort((x,y)=>x.fruitInBasket-y.fruitInBasket).map(({id},i)=>[id,i]))
// O(N)+O(NlogN)

homes.forEach(home=>{
const {familyMembers:fms} = home
const arr = new Array(fms.length)
//may want to prefill to maintain PACKED array: https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#avoid-creating-holes
for(const fm of fms) arr[ orderMap[fm.id] ] = fm
home.familyMembers = arr
})
// map lookup O(N)

console.log(homes)
```

```html
<script>
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    id: 1,
    fruitInBasket: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    id: 2,
    fruitInBasket: 9
  }
]
const homes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    familyMembers: [
      {
        name: 'James',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Steve',
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    familyMembers: [
      {
        name: 'James',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Steve',
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but look at mine, it's faster: https://jsben.ch/snN3M

Comment: You don't have enough objects in the data structures for the benchmark to be valid, and you've altered the entire data structure?  If it could be simplified like that, all you'd have to do was copy familyMembers in each array from one prebuilt array.  `find` and `sort` per loop couldn't possibly outperform hash lookups.

Comment: All you were measuring was the speed of object intiialization and overhead of calling console.log, the difference is substantial with any kind of size of data:  https://jsben.ch/fGjA6   This difference was this large for only 1000 homes.  You even left in console.log in the benchmark.

Comment: And your new function actually performs slightly worse, due to losing native array optimizations by using nothing but objects: https://jsben.ch/4FblY

Comment: @user120242 woah your totally right - way faster - I will mark this as the correct answer - thank you so much

Comment: Before you decide you should measure with real world data.  This benchmark does _not_ mean that this algorithm will outperform djcaesar9114 code in all cases. 
 Important that you read my comment above on your question.  There are cases where this approach would be suboptimal, just like sometimes O(N^2) or even O(N^3) algorithms can outperform quicksort if the data is of a certain characteristic.  Considerations like memory use also can come into play.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and sort:

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    id: 1,
    fruitInBasket: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    id: 2,
    fruitInBasket: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'Cesar',
    id: 3,
    fruitInBasket: 14
  }
]

const homes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    familyMembers: [
      {
        name: 'James',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Cesar',
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Steve',
        id: 1
      }
      
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    familyMembers: [
      {
        name: 'James',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Steve',
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]

homes.forEach(function(home){
  home.familyMembers.sort((a,b)=>people.find(x=>x.id == a.id).fruitInBasket - people.find(x=>x.id == b.id).fruitInBasket)
})

console.log(homes)
```

Explanations:

You will iterate through homes:

```
homes.forEach(function(home){
```

You will sort the members:

```
.familyMembers.sort((a,b)
```

To sort, you have to get the fruits of the members, so you find the correct ID then take the correct property:

```
people.find(x=>x.id == a.id).fruitInBasket
```

Then you compare:

```
(a,b)=>people.find(x=>x.id == a.id).fruitInBasket - people.find(x=>x.id == b.id).fruitInBasket
```

If what you're looking for is performance, you should change `people` strucutre:

```
const people = {
  1:  {
    name: 'Steve',
    fruitInBasket: 6
  },
  2: {
    name: 'James',
    fruitInBasket: 4
  }
}
```

This way you can retrieve fruits more easily:

```
people[id].fruits
```

Also, if your "id" is defined somewhere, don't define it in another place. Your `homes` should look like this:

```
const homes = {
  1:  {
    familyMembers: [1, 2, 3]  
  },
  2: {
    familyMembers: [1,2]
  }
}
```

So your algorithm goes like this:

```js
const people = {
  1:  {
    name: 'Steve',
    fruitInBasket: 6
  },
  3: {
    name: 'James',
    fruitInBasket: 4
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Cesar',
    fruitInBasket: 9114
  }
}

const homes = {
  1:  {
    familyMembers: [1, 2, 3]  
  },
  2: {
    familyMembers: [1,2]
  }
}

Object.keys(homes).forEach(function(k){
  homes[k].familyMembers.sort((a,b)=>people[a].fruitInBasket - people[b].fruitInBasket)
})

console.log(homes)
```

Comment: Not sure how this solves my time complexity issue? It's still On(^2)

Comment: You have to iterate through homes, this one is uncompressible. Then you have the sort(). If you want to improve the complexity, there may be something to look for at this point but you can benchmark my code, I think it's pretty good, I mean it's faster than what you posted initially :P

Comment: Could you please explain how it's faster than my implementation? Not trying to be rude or anything I just don't know - Thanks

Comment: I understand, no problem. You can compare scripts here: https://jsben.ch/ 
But I think you should change `people` structure if you want performance: `people` should be an object with the IDs as keys. This way you can retrieve you elements faster.

Comment: You're welcome, I proposed a new version of the algorithm with the new structure.

Comment: Performance characteristics for both algs is pretty bad.  O(N^3 * log N) and O(N^2 * log N).  This is worse than the OP's alg.  You're just lucky the number of people in a family probably stays around 5, so it doesn't grow out of control and crash your code.